# Button click to ctrl key mnemonic in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a button in a JFrame. When I click the button, I want to associate the click event with a mnemonic. Say for instance, if I click the button named `Cut`, I want `ctrl+x` to be executed and the selected text to be cut.

```
 jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {


        }
    });
```

What is the action to be performed to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the default Action provided by the editor kit:

```
JButton cut = new JButton( new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction() );
```

This can also be used to create a JMenuItem.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is - use [Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

This will allow you to associate a single `Action` with any number of supporting classes, notably all classes that extend from `AbstractAction` like, `JMenuItem` and `JButton`

Answer (score 0):

try using this `button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);` for more info read from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html